# How to Install Android Studio when OS is 32 Bit?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to Install Android Studio. But My Operating System is 32 bit and Android Studio is Download the [Link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (I think it is 64 bit)

and Installing SDK tools this [Link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)

and JDK is Use Version 8.

and I also Set JAVA_HOME in System Variables in Environment Variables in Advance system settings,
Variable name:JAVA_HOME
Variable value:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

But It give me Error When opening SDK Manager.

Error:
Cannot launch SDK manager.
Output:

'"D:\XYZ\ANDROI~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java32.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads)

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html)

Comment: Android Studio offers both a 32bit download and a 64bit download.  I believe it will auto detect which one your computer is

Comment: is your jdk 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: jdk install is 32 bit.

Comment: my os is 32 bit and jdk ia also 32 bit

Comment: You are on Windows, Android Studio for Windows has both 32 and 64bit versions.

Comment: ya but plz give me link for 32 bit

Comment: @Mark My computer Operating system is 32 bit

Comment: @Der Golem Ya Sorry I am talking about Android Studio

Comment: i dont think android supports JDK 8 , download version 7.

Comment: The JDK 8 definitely works. I think you forgot a "\" on the environment variable. Try C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\

Comment: @momo I can try \ but it is again not work

Comment: open the cmd and enter "java -version" - what is the output?

Comment: `give me link for 32 bit` There is 1 link only. The installer will choose which version to install, basing on your current OS.

Answer (score 4):

Just download the [32 bit version](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows32.zip).

Then extract the folder and go to: AndroidStudio > android-studio > bin

Then click on the "Android Studio" application.

Answer (score 3):

Download the 32bit version. The weird thing is it isn't a .exe, you have to extract the zip to somewhere you'll find it (I put it in my Documents folder). When you want to run studio, navigate to the extracted .zip, open `android-studio\bin` then run `studio.exe`. I also made a shortcut on my desktop to open it whenever I need to. Hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

download the .zip version and copy the Android Studio folder to ProgramFiles folder and run studio.exe for 32-bits

Answer (score 0):

After downloading android studio 32 version zip file extract it in a drive where it can be accessed easily then go to extracted folder

then 2-click on android-studio
     3-click on bin  [*image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttlhr.png) 
     4-click on android(.exe) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsjwZ.png)
u can make a shortcut in desktop,or u can access it from exact this location.